# mongodb next is not a function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I was working with this project, it is linked to mongodb, it was working perfectly, so I could register new users, edit and save them. I format my laptop, then I cloned my project but it doesn't work anymore, when I try to register a new user it gives me the error: "NEXT IS NOT A FUNCTION", I haven't modified anything.  I don't know really what happened. I have tried it in a different laptop and it works. So I have to keep working on it but I can't because of it.

I leave some code in case if it is something wrong.

Thanks!

- ### server.js

  ```
  var express = require("express"); // ExperssJS Framework
  var app = express(); // Invoke express to variable for use in application
  var port = process.env.PORT || 5555; // Set default port or assign a port in enviornment
  var morgan = require("morgan"); // Import Morgan Package
  var mongoose = require("mongoose"); // HTTP request logger middleware for Node.js
  var bodyParser = require("body-parser"); // Node.js body parsing middleware. Parses incoming request bodies in a middleware before your handlers, available under req.body.
  var router = express.Router(); // Invoke the Express Router
  var appRoutes = require("./app/routes/api")(router); // Import the application end points/API
  var path = require("path"); // Import path module
  var passport = require("passport"); // Express-compatible authentication middleware for Node.js.
  var social = require("./app/passport/passport")(app, passport); // Import passport.js End Points/API

  app.use(morgan("dev")); // Morgan Middleware
  app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Body-parser middleware
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // For parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public")); // Allow front end to access public folder
  app.use("/api", appRoutes); // Assign name to end points (e.g., '/api/management/', '/api/users' ,etc. )

  //
  // <---------- REPLACE WITH YOUR MONGOOSE CONFIGURATION ---------->
  //
  mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb://localhost:27017/databasename",
    { useNewUrlParser: true },
    function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Not connected to the database: " + err); // Log to console if unable to connect to database
      } else {
        console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB"); // Log to console if able to connect to database
      }
    }
  );

  // Set Application Static Layout
  app.get("*", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/app/views/index.html")); // Set index.html as layout
  });

  // Start Server
  app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Running the server on port " + port); // Listen on configured port
  });
  ```

    -

### userCtrl.js

```
    angular
  .module("userControllers", ["userServices"])

  // Controller: regCtrl is used for users to register an account
  .controller("regCtrl", function($http, $location, $timeout, User, $scope) {
    var app = this;

    // Custom function that registers the user in the database
    this.regUser = function(regData, valid, confirmed) {
      app.disabled = true; // Disable the form when user submits to prevent multiple requests to server
      app.loading = true; // Activate bootstrap loading icon
      app.errorMsg = false; // Clear errorMsg each time user submits
      // If form is valid and passwords match, attempt to create user
      if (valid && confirmed) {
        app.regData.name = app.regData.firstName + " " + app.regData.lastName; // Combine first and last name before submitting to database
        // Runs custom function that registers the user in the database
        User.create(app.regData).then(function(data) {
          // Check if user was saved to database successfully
          if (data.data.success) {
            app.loading = false; // Stop bootstrap loading icon
            $scope.alert = "alert alert-success"; // Set class for message
            app.successMsg = data.data.message + "...Redirecting"; // If successful, grab message from JSON object and redirect to login page
            // Redirect after 2000 milliseconds (2 seconds)
            $timeout(function() {
              $location.path("/login");
            }, 2000);
          } else {
            app.loading = false; // Stop bootstrap loading icon
            app.disabled = false; // If error occurs, remove disable lock from form
            $scope.alert = "alert alert-danger"; // Set class for message
            app.errorMsg = data.data.message; // If not successful, grab message from JSON object
          }
        });
      } else {
        app.disabled = false; // If error occurs, remove disable lock from form
        app.loading = false; // Stop bootstrap loading icon
        $scope.alert = "alert alert-danger"; // Set class for message
        app.errorMsg = "Please ensure form is filled our properly"; // Display error if valid returns false
      }
    };

    //  Custom function that checks if username is available for user to use
    this.checkUsername = function(regData) {
      app.checkingUsername = true; // Start bootstrap loading icon
      app.usernameMsg = false; // Clear usernameMsg each time user activates ngBlur
      app.usernameInvalid = false; // Clear usernameInvalid each time user activates ngBlur

      // Runs custom function that checks if username is available for user to use
      User.checkUsername(app.regData).then(function(data) {
        // Check if username is available for the user
        if (data.data.success) {
          app.checkingUsername = false; // Stop bootstrap loading icon
          app.usernameMsg = data.data.message; // If successful, grab message from JSON object
        } else {
          app.checkingUsername = false; // Stop bootstrap loading icon
          app.usernameInvalid = true; // User variable to let user know that the chosen username is taken already
          app.usernameMsg = data.data.message; // If not successful, grab message from JSON object
        }
      });
    };

    // Custom function that checks if e-mail is available for user to use
    this.checkEmail = function(regData) {
      app.checkingEmail = true; // Start bootstrap loading icon
      app.emailMsg = false; // Clear emailMsg each time user activates ngBlur
      app.emailInvalid = false; // Clear emailInvalid each time user activates ngBlur

      // Runs custom function that checks if e-mail is available for user to use
      User.checkEmail(app.regData).then(function(data) {
        // Check if e-mail is available for the user
        if (data.data.success) {
          app.checkingEmail = false; // Stop bootstrap loading icon
          app.emailMsg = data.data.message; // If successful, grab message from JSON object
        } else {
          app.checkingEmail = false; // Stop bootstrap loading icon
          app.emailInvalid = true; // User variable to let user know that the chosen e-mail is taken already
          app.emailMsg = data.data.message; // If not successful, grab message from JSON object
        }
      });
    };
    app.addUser = function() {
      if (app.showTheForm) {
        app.showTheForm = false;
        app.expand = false;
      } else {
        app.showTheForm = true;
        app.expand = true;
      }
    };
  })

  // Custom directive to check matching passwords
  .directive("match", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A", // Restrict to HTML Attribute
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.confirmed = false; // Set matching password to false by default

        // Custom function that checks both inputs against each other
        $scope.doConfirm = function(values) {
          // Run as a loop to continue check for each value each time key is pressed
          values.forEach(function(ele) {
            // Check if inputs match and set variable in $scope
            if ($scope.confirm == ele) {
              $scope.confirmed = true; // If inputs match
            } else {
              $scope.confirmed = false; // If inputs do not match
            }
          });
        };
      },

      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        // Grab the attribute and observe it
        attrs.$observe("match", function() {
          scope.matches = JSON.parse(attrs.match); // Parse to JSON
          scope.doConfirm(scope.matches); // Run custom function that checks both inputs against each other
        });

        // Grab confirm ng-model and watch it
        scope.$watch("confirm", function() {
          scope.matches = JSON.parse(attrs.match); // Parse to JSON
          scope.doConfirm(scope.matches); // Run custom function that checks both inputs against each other
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

- ### Node.js

  { ValidationError: User validation failed: username: next is not a 
  function, password: next is not a function, email: next is not a function, name: next is not a function
          at ValidationError.inspect (D:\Documents\Trabajo\gorotasnewest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:56:24)
          at ValidationError.deprecated (internal/util.js:70:15)
          at formatValue (util.js:467:31)
          at inspect (util.js:328:10)
          at Object.formatWithOptions (util.js:182:12)
          at Console.(anonymous function) (console.js:188:15)
          at Console.log (console.js:199:31)
          at D:\Documents\Trabajo\gorotasnewest\app\routes\api.js:70:17
          at D:\Documents\Trabajo\gorotasnewest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4423:16
          at $__save.error (D:\Documents\Trabajo\gorotasnewest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:379:16)
          at D:\Documents\Trabajo\gorotasnewest\node_modules\kareem\index.js:246:48
          at next (D:\Documents\Trabajo\gorotasnewest\node_modules\kareem\index.js:167:27)
          at Kareem.execPost (D:\Documents\Trabajo\gorotasnewest\node_modules\kareem\index.js:217:3)
          at _handleWrapError (D:\Documents\Trabajo\gorotasnewest\node_modules\kareem\index.js:245:21)
          at D:\Documents\Trabajo\gorotasnewest\node_modules\kareem\index.js:272:14
          at _next (D:\Documents\Trabajo\gorotasnewest\node_modules\kareem\index.js:94:14)
        errors:
         { username:
            { ValidatorError: next is not a function
                at new ValidatorError (D:\Documents\Trabajo\gorotasnewest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validator.js:25:11)
                at validate (D:\Documents\Trabajo\gorotasnewest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:805:13)
                at D:\Documents\Trabajo\gorotasnewest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:854:11
                at Array.forEach ()
                at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (D:\Documents\Trabajo\gorotasnewest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:814:19)

Comment: Angular tag is for versions of Angular 2+. You are using angular 1.x.x therefore you should change your tag

Comment: This is your server code only, you should share the code to your schema definition, the error says you are trying call a function next inside your API which is not defined in your schema for user. Share ./app/routes/api and if you have user schema files separately share them as well.

Comment: @Babak the API is too big to post here, I can run it without issues on Linux but on windows, it doesn't work at all...

Comment: Sorry I never got a notification back from your question, I hope your problem is solved by now.

Comment: @Babak I have finished the project but on Linux, thanks anyways.